# Vue props not passing correctly

Tags: vue.js

I have a component

In the component I have

```
export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: ['showFooter'],
}
```

Then in the template i have

```
<template>
   <div class='modal'>
       <div class='footer' v-if='showFooter'>This is the footer</div>
   </div>
</template>
```

THe footer doesnt display at all, if i pass the prop or not.  It just says

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "showFooter" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Whats the issue here??

Ive also just tried

```
<template>
   <div class='modal'>
       <div class='footer' v-if='showFoot'>This is the footer</div>
   </div>
</template>    

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: ['showFooter'],
  data(){
    return {
       showFoot:this.showFooter
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get told showFoot isnt defined.  Which is even wierder because Im defining it right there in the data!??

Even if I just remove the property totally, and just define it in data

```
export default {
  name: "Modal",
  data(){
    return {
       showFoot:true
    }
  }
}
```

I still get

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "showFoot" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

So wierd and I cant for the life of me figure it out

Its almost like the template has no access to anything I define in the data() or props of the componenet.  Never seen this before

Comment: Is your component a single-file component (eg `Modal.vue`)? If so, could you show how it's defined with `<template>` and `<script>` sections (rather than separate blocks as above)? If it is not a single-file component, how is the `<template>` linked to the `export default {...}` script?

Comment: No idea why this worked.  But I copied all the code into a new file, saved it as ModalWindow.vue, and redclared it in my main.js file.  Now it all works fine.  I literally did nothing except renamed it and redclared it.  (got rid of the old Modal.vue file).  So maybe Modal or <modal> as a component/name, was clashing with something?? (vue bootstrap? I seriously have no clue)  Works fine now though :)  I should probably delete this question, since this seemed to be more of a compilation error / voodoo than an actual Vue.js code question

Answer (score 0):

i think so you are not passing props from parent component. Ideally you can pass it from parent component and receive it in Children.

`<childComponent :yourPropNameInChild="anyDataFromParentYouWantToPass" />`

here this ChildComponent is rendered in your parent component.

to receive it in children you can do

`export default {
  name: "Modal",
  props: ['yourPropNameInChild'],
}`

as of for your example

`<modal :showFooter="showFooter" />`

in your parent you have to write above line of code

and in your child you have to receive it as you are doing

also in your example you were missing `script` tag

Comment: Yeah thats not it.  I thought it had something to do with props, but have since figured out that even if I just define data()  inside the component (not even considering props at all),  I still dont have access.  See my last iteration above.  So if I just define   something like   testText:"Here is my test"  and then try {{testText}} it into the template I get the same error.  Almost like the ttemplate has no access to any variables

Comment: that's weird ideally it should be returning true. Will it be possible to create a fiddle with the code

Comment: No I dont think so, because its all ES6.  I think its some wierd compilation error

Comment: wait a minute is your export default inside a `<script>` `</script>` ? i mean you can right Js inside `<script>` only